# Use compression during Database backup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sql-server, backup, restore

In some circumstances, we can use compression to decrease the size of backups and the time to complete each backup. 
I use following command to restore site.

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase "MyDatabase" -DatabaseServer "MyServer" -WebApplication http://sitename
```

Is there any impact to the new site or changes due to database compression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not seeing any issue, as long as you have healthy backup file at end. SharePoint dont care if you backup file was compressed or not. You have to restore the database and attach it to the SQL then running the mount command will attach it to SharePoint.

You have to always test, if anything on the environment creating any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Backup compression increases CPU usage and this can affect SQL Server concurrent operations.

But there wont be any data loss

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have go through [Backup Compression (SQL Server)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-compression-sql-server#PerfImpact) and from the description , compression significantly increases CPU usage, and the additional CPU consumed by the compression process might adversely impact concurrent operations. Besides , i couldn't see there are any issue if you restore using compression backup .